# ionic alert mandatory input

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 for my new app and I need to make inputs taken from my ionic-alert controller to be mandatory. Went through ionic-component documentation and api documentation, but could not find how to do this. Below is my code. I want to make *name* and *mobile* inputs to be mandatory and disable *Continue button* until both are filled.

```
let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Tell us about yourself',
        message: "Please provide us your name, and mobile number",
        inputs: [
        {
          name: 'name',
          placeholder: 'Name'
        },
        {
          name: 'mobile',
          placeholder: 'Mobile number'
        },],
        buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Continue',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Continue clicked');
          }
        }]
        });
        prompt.present();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment you **cannot do** this. But using data validation rules where you can prevent the user from entering invalid data.

Here I have used `toast` notifications for invalid data.

```
{
  text: 'Done',
  handler: (data) => {
    if (EmailValidator.isValid(data.email)) {
      if (this.data) {
        //
      } else {
       //
      }
      return true;
    } else {
      this.showErrorToast('Invalid Email');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anybody still looking for a workaround, here is what I did, not only in Ionic 3 but in Ionic 4 as well.

You can make your inputs mandatory, validate data upon confirmation or even update the alert message by using some **DOM manipulation** through the `document` object.

Basically you want to open your alert and query all your inputs or buttons that you are interested in. Then you can add some listeners to you inputs to enable or disable any other element.

## Example (Ionic 4)

```
    const alert = await this.alertCntrl.create({
      header: 'Alert!',
      subHeader: 'Delete item',
      message: 'Please fill the following code to confirm deletion: XYZ',
      inputs: [{type: 'text', placeholder: 'Confirmation code', id: 'code'}],
      buttons: [
        {text: 'Confirm', handler: _data => this.deleteItem(), cssClass: 'confirm'},
        {text: 'Cancel', role: 'cancel'},
      ],
    });
    await alert.present();

    const code$ = new Subject();

    const confirmBtn = document.querySelector('.confirm') as HTMLButtonElement;
    confirmBtn.disabled = true;

    const codeInput = document.getElementById('code') as HTMLInputElement;

    codeInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => codigo$.next(codeInput.value));

    code$.asObservable().subscribe(code => confirmBtn.disabled = code !== 'XYZ');
```

To show that the button is disable I have added some css to ionic **global.scss**

```
// This will match the class that we set up to the btn in the alert config.
// and color the btn text to grey only when it is disabled
button.confirm:disabled {
  color: grey;
}
```